# XPath Selenium Invalid xpath [2]

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, xpath

I am using selenium for flash test. I want to get `id` of an embed tag.
I used firepath to get xapth and it looks like `html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/embed`

And when I am trying to retrieve it like

```
browser.getAttribute(("xpath=//[html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/embed]"));
```

then I am getting `com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //*[html/body/div[2]/div[6]/object/embedd`

I am using selenium 2 RC. Please anybody help to get the `id` attribute inside embed tag.

Comment: very good link for using xpaths: http://test-able.blogspot.ie/2016/04/xpath-selectors-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using getAttribute incorrectly. Selenium's `getAttribute` method takes an attributeLocator as its parameter. The attribute locator, as the docs describe, is an element locator (in this case, your xpath) followed by "@" and the name of the attribute (in this case, id).

Try

```
String xpath = "xpath=//[html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/embed]";
browser.getAttribute(xpath+"@id");
```

Also double-check your code. You say in your code you wrote `div[1]` but the error says `div[2]` - it's possible you just made a typo. That would explain the xpath error, although you still need to correct your use of getAttribute as well.

[Selenium getAttribute docs.](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)